# Обрезка строк в ListView

Tags: android, java, экран

Доброго времени суток!

У меня такой вопрос. Допустим, у меня есть ListView, в каждом элементе которого есть TextView с каким-то текстом. Текст может быть разной длины, в том числе может и не умещаться  на экране. Я написал функцию, которая обрезает строку и дополняет ее тремя точками, если она больше 30 символов:

```
public static String reduce(String text) {
    return text.length() <= 30 ? text : text.substring(0, 27) + "...";
}
```

И это вроде работает. Но проблема в том, что приложение может запускаться на устройствах с разными размерами экранов и к тому же может использоваться разный размер шрифта, поэтому в каждом таком случае должно быть свое  количество символов вместо тридцати. 
Например, если размер экрана 1024х768, то строка должна быть не больше 30 символов, если 1920х108, то 50 символов и так далее.

Как поступить в таком случае? Как правильно обрезать строку в зависимости от размера экрана и размера шрифта, чтобы она всегда помещалась на экране и при этом имела максимальный возможный размер?

Comment: @JuniorTwo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Уже всё придумано за вас http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize